# Fetch db data depending on selected drop down value

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to fetch data from db upon changing value of my drop down, I want to pull up the data that corresponds to the value of the drop down and show it to a text area, I got the codes that I've tried to create just don't know how to make it work to what I want.

I want my page to just initially show the drop down then after selecting a value it will show the data in a text area without refreshing the page, here is the code:

```
<div id="mainContent">
<table width="619" border="0" align="center">
<td align="center"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>EA</strong></legend>
<p> 
<select name="ea_name" id="ea_name">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form></td>
</table>

<div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

I am thinking an "onchange" could do it but just dont know how to implement it, also want to echo the resulting data to a text area within a fieldset.

Here is the code that I've tried that will pull up data and show to a text area:

```
<?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$ea_name = $_POST['ea_name'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM ea_error WHERE ea_name = '" . $ea_name . "'";

$myData = mysql_query($sql);

//to count if there are any results
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($myData);

if($numrow == 0)
{
    echo "No results found.";
}
else
{
echo "<fieldset><legend><strong>Information</strong></legend><p>
<table width="auto" height="172" border="0">
<tr><th scope="row">Error</th></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Resolution</th></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Contact/s</th></tr>;"

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
{
echo "<form action='retrieve.php' method='post'>";

echo"<tr>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['error'] . "<input type=hidden name=error value=" . $info['error'] . " </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['resolution'] . "<input type=hidden name=resolution value=" . $info['resolution'] . " size='11' maxlength='11' /> </td>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['contacts'] . "<input type=hidden name=contacts value=" . $info['contacts'] . "' /> </td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "</form>";
}
}
echo "</fieldset>"; 

include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
<?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$ea_name = $_POST['ea_name'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM ea_error WHERE ea_name = '" . $ea_name . "'";

$myData = mysql_query($sql);

//to count if there are any results
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($myData);

if($numrow == 0)
{
    echo "No results found.";
}
else
{
echo '<fieldset><legend><strong>Information</strong></legend><p>
<table width="auto" height="172" border="0">
<tr><th>Error</th></tr>
<tr><th>Resolution</th></tr>
<tr><th>Contact/s</th></tr>';

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
{
echo "<form action='retrieve.php' method='post'>";

echo"<tr>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['error'] . "<input type=hidden name=error value=" . $info['error'] . " </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['resolution'] . "<input type=hidden name=resolution value=" . $info['resolution'] . " size='11' maxlength='11' /> </td>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['contacts'] . "<input type=hidden name=contacts value=" . $info['contacts'] . "' /> </td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "</form>";
}
}
echo "</fieldset>"; 

include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Just put this javascript either in script tags in the head of your page, after the jQuery include, or in another js file and include that after jQuery...

```
$(function() {  //  document.ready
    $("#ea_name").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "phpfile.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ea_name: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#results").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It assigns an event handler to the change event of the drop down.  When this is triggered it sends an ajax request to your php file (don't forget to put the correct filename for the url!) which then returns the html.  This is then pushed into the results div.

**Note:** I fixed a typo that may or may not be in your php file.  At the end of the line where you create the query, you'd missed a closing ".  Just in case that was a copy and paste from the real file.

Comment: Also try to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` functions.

Comment: @NikhilMohan - that's up to the OP.  I'm just trying to answer the question that has been asked :)

Comment: It's ok. Your answer is perfect. I'm just trying to give a suggestion :)

Comment: @NikhilMohan I hope he appreciates it - I'm no php expert at all!! Thanks :)

Comment: @Archer thanks for the code, it seems to work but im getting an error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'auto' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\retrieve.php on line 26; think  i have some code error in my retrieve.php file.

Comment: @user2579439 in your `else { echo "....`, you have a quote issue. change it from `echo "<fieldset> ... </th></tr>;"` to `echo '<fieldset> ... </th></tr>';`. Since you are using double quotes in your fields/table, change your wrapping double quotes to single quotes, and put the semi-colon after the final single quote.

Comment: @Sean thanks for the help...pls see my updated code above...still dont seem to work, as im just getting: No results found. it should pull up data that corresponds to the select value and show it to the text area within fieldset...

Comment: @user2579439 Do you have rows in your db that have an `ea_name` value of `1`,`2`,`3`,or `4`? If you are only getting `No results found`, then you need to verify if there are rows in your db that match your selected value.

Comment: @Sean yes i have a column name `ea_name` and those values in my db.

Comment: @user2579439 So if you are getting `No results found` then `if($numrow == 0)` is returning `true`. So you need to figure out why there are `0` number of rows returned. Some things you can do to debug: 1. echo `$sql` and try it directly in your db to make sure it is a valid query and returning row(s); 2. check if there are errors using `mysql_error()` -  `$myData = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`; 3. Make sure that `$_POST['ea_name']` has a valid value - `echo $ea_name`.

Comment: @Sean ive changed my code to: `$sql="SELECT * FROM ea_error WHERE ea_name = '" . $ea_name . "'";
echo $sql;` then try it again, i got this result in the page: SELECT * FROM ea_error WHERE ea_name = '1'
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\retrieve.php on line 18
No results found.

Comment: @Archer apologize for hijacking your answer comments. did +1 for your answer though.

Comment: @user2579439 your query is failing, so it is probably returning `false` (which is `boolean`, not a resource). Add the `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of your `mysql_query()` - `$myData = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`. Have you verified your db connection? Also, you can find over 176 example of that `Warning` by searching SO http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A+mysql_num_rows%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given

Comment: @Sean No worries.  I turn my back for a few hours and this happens! lol :)

Comment: @Sean my bad...code seems fine...just needs some aesthetics enhancement...real issue is my `require 'include/DB_Open.php';`...i doubled check it and its trying to connect to my other db...thanks for all the help mann :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement ajax call to php file with ea_name as post parameter file. and place response to specific div.